# Why the sound not working when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I tried to play sound when the page is loaded, but it's not working never but when I click on button the sound is working.

*JavaScript*

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        let audio = new Audio('sounds/sound.mp3');
        let is_play = true;
        let btn = document.getElementById("sound_btn");
        audio.play();
        $("#" + btn.getAttribute("id")).click(function () {
            if (is_play) {
                btn.innerText = "Play Sound";
                is_play = false
                audio.pause();
            } else {
                btn.innerText = "Pause Sound";
                is_play = true;
                audio.play();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Some browsers are now preventing auto play without user interaction or user allowing it in preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re probably using Google chrome which prevents playing audio files upon loading, you can check your log for such an error.

Audio files has to has to be played after a user’s event (as clicking).

Comment: My way of working around this (which I thought was pretty clever, if I do say so) was to have a fairly obvious "Mute Sound ☑" checkbox, defaulted to checked. Unchecking it requires a human interaction, and now the browser allows you to play sound all you want. Bonus points for not blaring noises at an unsuspecting user!